# Is there a way to create an Orange color from ANSI escape characters?

Tags: ansi-escape

I am looking for a control code to create orange text in a terminal using ANSI or some other standard, is this possible? I only see yellow and red available, and I don't think you can mix red and yellow for the same character :)

Comment: The brown yellow might do the job, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: yeah, thanks, but I can't figure out what the code is for that

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Strictly speaking, no: ANSI never standardized anything (for a terminal's control sequences) which was called "orange".  Some terminals can do this, but that lies outside the scope of the standards.

xterm (see [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)) uses control sequences following the "ANSI" (actually withdrawn from standardization long ago) [ECMA-48](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm) syntax.

- Some of those are the standard 8 colors via SGR (which do not include orange).
- It also (using the aixterm SGR *extension*) adds another 8 colors.  Still no orange.
- However, xterm extends (in a way not exactly standard) SGR codes 38 and 48 to provide a palette of colors using RGB (red/green/blue) values.  The maximum palette size is compiled in as either 88 or 256 colors.

*Orange* can be composed by an RGB code.  For instance X's rgb.txt file defines it as

```
255 165   0             orange
```

(bright red plus a moderately bright green).  To get that in a shell script, one could use

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "\033[48:2:255:165:0m%s\033[m\n" "Hello world"
printf "\033[48;2;255;165;0m%s\033[m\n" "Hello world"
```

The difference between the two lines is the use of colon as a parameter separator (ECMA-48 has some verbiage which prefers that, for *subparameters* as used in xterm, which was overlooked early on).  For compatibility (including with terminals copied from xterm's early implementation), xterm honors both.

xterm also supports a "non-ANSI" scheme referred to as *dynamic colors*, which accepts a color *name*, but that sets the text color for the whole screen.

Finally, xterm can assign colors to display instead of blink, bold, italics, reverse and underline (see the discussion of `colorBD` for instance).  That is done though X resource settings (with some help from escape sequences).  The colors assigned to those resources can be set via the same 88/256 color extension.

Comment: Cruel syntax but brilliant when it works! For me, the variant with the semicolons is working in my python scripts which print to a file which is then typed in jenkins. All on windows 7. Like so: `orangeBg = "\033[48;2;255;165;0m"` Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

The [256-color palette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#8-bit) is more compatible and a tad easier to use.  There are a number of oranges:

```bash
printf "\033[48:5:208m%s\033[m\n" "Hello world"  # bright orange
printf "\033[48:5:166m%s\033[m\n" "Hello world"  # darker orange
```

The colons may need to be semi-colons under your terminal.  Change the first number to 38, to set the foreground instead.  The second number (5) means use the 256 color palette, and the third number selects the indexed color.