# How to make Macbook Terminal text less transparent

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I've recently tinkered with my .bash_profile to change the color and formatting of my Terminal command prompt. Unfortunately, in doing so, I've also caused for any text that I type in to appear in a very transparent shade:

[image]

Below are the contents of my .bash_profile:

```
PS1="\[\033[0;35m\]\u\[\033[1;33m\]@\[\033[1;33m\]\w\[\033[0;32m\]\$ "
export PS1;

export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=Gafxcxdxbxegedabagacad
```

How might my .bash_profile file be modified to make all text as bright/bold as the bold-green and bold-yellow text shown in the image?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the PS1 variable using escape codes is tedious and often has side effects.  I did it that way for years, and line wrapping was often broken.  I tested your PS1 in a terminal window.  Seems that something is not terminated correctly as the color bleeds into the following line.  I use tput to set PS1, which makes the assignment more readable.  Here is what I have in .bash_profile:

```
set_prompt() {
local red=$(tput setaf 1)
local green=$(tput setaf 2)
local yellow=$(tput setaf 3)
local blue=$(tput setaf 4)
local magenta=$(tput setaf 5)
local cyan=$(tput setaf 6)
local white=$(tput setaf 7)
local reset=$(tput sgr0)

if [ ${UID} -eq 0 ]; then
    # user is red when we are root
    export PS1="\[$red\]\u\[$white\]@\[$green\]\h\[$white\]:\[$yellow\]\w [$reset\]$ "
else
    export PS1="\[$blue\]\u\[$white\]@\[$green\]\h\[$white\]:\[$yellow\]\w\[$reset\]$ "
fi;
```

}

```
# Don't set the prompt for dumb terminals
if [ ${TERM+x} -a "${TERM-}" != "dumb" ]; then
    set_prompt
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The brighter text was from this chunk, which sets the bold attribute **`1`**:

```
\[\033[1;33m\]
```

and the text is left dim because you omitted bold at the end:

```
\[\033[0;32m\]
```

The **`32`** and **`33`** select colors *green* and *yellow*, respectively, but without the ***bold*** attribute, most terminals display that as **brown**.

Further reading

- [*How can I set the brown color using ANSI escape sequence?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34201443/how-can-i-set-the-brown-color-using-ansi-escape-sequence/34202262#34202262)
- [*Is there a way to create an Orange color from ANSI escape characters?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573654/is-there-a-way-to-create-an-orange-color-from-ansi-escape-characters/33027863#33027863)
- [*XTerm Control Sequences*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)

Answer (score -1):

I am using macbook too but I don't use the default terminal application. I use iTerm, it is really more flexible and can be configured as how you want it to display things.